# Build one job from another job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have two jobs in Jenkins A, B.

B is dependent on job A. So, whenever I Build Job B, automatically Job A should build first and then the job B.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the configuration of the job B you can select the Build-Trigger "start build after other projects were built" and there choose A as the build before.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is the exact answer if i had only two jobs in jenkins and one is dependent on another. but if i had more than three jobs and all of them were dependent on one particular job, then how can i proceed?

For Eg: I had 4 jobs A,B,C,D. All B,C,D jobs were independent on each other but they all dependent on A. So if i want to Build a job, Say B, it should automatically trigger a new build for job A and then continue with the build of job 'B'

Comment: The same. Specify A as the build-trigger in every job.

Comment: I specified A As the build-trigger in job B and built B. Unfortunately that did not triggered any build for Job A

Comment: Trigger A manually, B gets triggered automatically when job A is done.